# How do I use QAxWidget class to display PDF files with QT codes

Tags: c++, qt, com, adobe-reader

I use QAxWidget to display my pdf files,but when I finish the codes and run my own program,it shows

> "There is a problem whith Adobe Acrobat/Reader. If is running ,please exit and try again."

I have already install the software of `AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe` before I run my own program.

I run the `Adobe Reader XI`,choose the `Edit->Preferences->Security(Enhanced)`  and cancel `Enable Protected Mode at startup`,but It doesn't work.

```
QAxWidget *m_pPDFwidget;
m_pPDFwidget = new QAxWidget("Microsoft Web Browser");
QString strFilePath = "C:/1.pdf";
m_pPDFwidget->dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", strFilePath );
```